# Get the list of extracted files when using Recursive Extraction Library

Tags: coq

`Recursive Extraction Library` generates multiple `.ml` and `.mli` files. Is it possible to print the list of generated files during the extraction ?

The best I have come up with is to note that generated files begin with a capital letter, but it is not optimal.

Answer (score 2):

Run your code through `coqtop` rather than through `coqc`:

```
$ echo 'Recursive Extraction Library Specif.' | coqtop
Welcome to Coq 8.6.1 (July 2017)

Coq < The file Logic.ml has been created by extraction.
The file Logic.mli has been created by extraction.
The file Datatypes.ml has been created by extraction.
The file Datatypes.mli has been created by extraction.
The file Specif.ml has been created by extraction.
The file Specif.mli has been created by extraction.

Coq <
```

If you want it to print when you run `coqc`, you should probably [submit a feature request](https://coq.inria.fr/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?bug_severity=enhancement&component=Extraction) for a command line flag or a setting.

Comment: Is it possible to print the same lines with a variant of `coqtop -load-vernac-source myFile.v` ?

Comment: There does not seem to be, though of course `cat myFile.v | coqtop` works.